# Does somebody know the Song to these lyrics?

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics, electronic-music

"you know what I came here for i came for you" + "throw it down and count to 3"

Heard the song on a stream and the streamer was speaking quite a lot so I couldn't make out more, but I'm about 90% certain that's exactly the words I heard and I've been looking for the song everywhere for around an hour without any results.

It wasn't the best song ever but I'm not the kind of guy to give up quickly.

It sounded like a more or less usual "house" song nowadays, not one of these Songs that are all about the drop though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this [Imagine - Bolier & Arem Ozguc & Arman Aydin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rDzO4PZKjU)

Has lyrics "Slow it down and count to three".
"you know what I came here for/ I came for you"

Comment: That's it, thank you! Got the same problem again, this time all I know is "It's a cage that holds me back" and that it sounds kinda like a typical house track or something, I will eventually find it!

Comment: if it's the right answer, pls "accept" it.  On the other track, suggest you go for variations of the words in searching, as words are often not clear